# Cruise Control batch file build never completes

Tags: tomcat, cruisecontrol

I am using cruise control to trigger a batch deploy script and currently the file executes perfectly BUT cruise control does not see the script end. It just keeps spinning (building) and this goes on forever.

My script launches downloads the build extracts it and then starts tomcat with the application deployed. The script also ends with:

```
exit /B 0
```

and yet cruise control does not see the script exiting...

Anyone has an idea

Comment: It seems that the child windows that are opened prevent the build from completing. When the windows are closed(manually) the build completes instantly

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop on this matter, the tags in the cruise control schedule are dumb when it comes to batch files. If the batch file starts application that are in separate windows the build process will not stop until the windows of those programs are stopped. The script I was using was launching tomcat in its own windows as it was a deployment script. Fortunately if you launch the windows from a vbs file instead of a batch the new window is not considered as a child process which is what we want for cruise control to finish its build.